# Finding Missing Imports

Tags: java, android, import

I am writing some android apps outside of an IDE, how would I go about finding missing imports? Right now my solution has been to google "import context android" and then search stack overflow answers for the missing imports, but somehow those have to be found somewhere in my environment. Are there tools out there to solve this? Or is there a way I can search manually for something (and ultimately write a "missing import script" on my own.

I suspect this may not be specific to android, but may be.

Comment: Why on earth are you writing Android apps without an IDE? I can appreciate a desire to become familiar with the command line tools, but I wouldn't try to develop a complete app with them.

Comment: To be honest getting the environment setup is a hassle, I was running on Ubuntu 12.04 at the time, I couldn't install the sun java 6, then I couldn't install "googles" android IDE, I have used eclipse before but felt like it took a long time. Once I discovered a few simple commands worked I was good to go. Including *trying* to figure out how to get the IDE built, I had a mostly working app in under 2 hours using the command line.

Comment: Simply wrtiting the code I need to and passing through a tool that adds any missing imports followed by "ant debug" and I would be good to go (I would like to include a "java beautifier" in the pipeline too, but that's another story)

Comment: Wait for it ...   Write code outside of IDE at your own risk.

Comment: I write c code outside an IDE, I'm a risky individual. However this question isn't about the decision whether to write code in or out of an IDE, the tools exist in the event someone wants to use them, I was hoping to hear either a tool exists or of a "simple" way to auto import. Looking in Androids page here as an example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/package-summary.html I see that I can pull all the class names from android.content, so now I can do regex to get most of the cases when I see that particular class being referenced